# How to make Firefox prompt for Windows's own certificate store's client certificates?

Tags: windows, firefox, client-certificate

As per this blog post it should be possible:
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/04/14/expanding-client-certificates-in-firefox-75/

Yet when browsing a site which asks for a client certificate it doesn't open a prompt. (On the same site the prompt happens when installing said certificate in Firefox's own store.)

This happens using Firefox 89.0.2, Windows 10. The server is nginx with `ssl_verify_client optional`

Comment: Did you changed the setting as described in the article?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf yup! And I now found the issue too: there is an "Authentication decision" tab in Firefox's Settings -> Privacy & Security -> View Certificates window. I had selected not to send the certificate once and that kept it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This does work, don't forget two things:

- `security.osclientcerts.autoload` to `true` (as mentioned in the linked blog post)
- clear the "Authentication decision" row for your website in Firefox's Settings -> Privacy & Security -> View Certificates if you had checked the (default) "Remember this decision" when picking a certificate.